# View the command used to make an item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Recently I had a sign that teleported me, and had nice letter color.  All I wanted to do was change the location I was teleported, but I didn't have the command to create that sign.  It's not a big deal to recreate the sign, but I was wondering if there was a shortcut that allowed me to re-view the command used to create the item.

Comment: I'm assuming the reason you're mentioning the colours is because you want to make it using the same?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to reuse the color, maybe there is a 3rd party tool that'll allow for what I'd like

Comment: /blockdata can be used to edit the data of entity blocks (signs, dispensers, etc.)

Comment: @Daniel G  I never really used that command, I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the exact command used to create the sign unless the command block that created it is still around, but you can look at its information like this:
`/blockdata <x> <y> <z> {}`

The command will technically fail, but its failure message will show you all of the block's data, including the command it ran to teleport you when you clicked on it.

Comment: Thank you for this, I haven't  used this command because I didn't know what it did